# React.js/socket.io bottleneck issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, create-react-app

I'm new to the react.js thing and started migrating an old pure HTML/CSS/JS front-end app to react.js, the app consists of receiving broadcasts with low latency, I used the create-react-app to create my project and now I'm facing a strange problem of bottlenecking on the react.js side.

I created a module on the app to handle the socket.io broadcasts but when I run the app there's a strange high latency when receiving the broadcasts.

[This is the latency time on the old js vanilla app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM0RI.png)

[This is the latency on the react.js app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AywQ0.png)

At first, I thought the problem was because the rendering took much time processing my requests synchronously because I'm using hooks with `useEffect` so I just imported the module and defined the broadcast event without rendering anything, but no improvement on the latency.

Then I created a simple client and ran it independently and the latency was good:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
//import io from 'socket.io-client';

socket = io.connect('------------------')

socket.on('connect', () =>{
  console.log("i'm connected to the server")
})

socket.on('broadcast_timer', data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

This is the code that basically is on the react.js, old vanilla, and on the simple client created.

I don't know if this is related to webpack, or hot-reloading (I made a build from the app and ran it but the problem persisted), does anyone had any problem like this handling sockets?

Answer (score 0):

Well, trying out everything like using a new create-react-app and building a react project manually configuring webpack and babel i gave up on using socket.io, it might me a bug having that latency discrepancy on react.js because i don't have it elsewhere and changed the server to use SSE(server-side-events) streaming which works very well and the client just needs to subscribe to the timer and no extra dependencies.